# DRF ViewSet: Change appearance of field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I have a model like this:

```
## model:
class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique = True)
    price = models.ForeignKey(Price, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True, blank = True)

## serializer:
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ["id", "price",]
```

which shows up in the template of the API like this:

[image]

I get, this is because of the nature of the model field type. Two questions here:

1. Can I get rid of the little arrows somehow and make a normal field?
   [image]
2. Could I somehow return a list of all Product ids like for the price? Something like `ids = Product.objects.values_list("id", flat = True)` or so?
   [image]

Comment: For your first question, the best solution would be to customize the admin view, like this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/

Comment: Do you want only to change the visual field on the API Browser, or to change the behavior of the field all along?
You can specify the field explicitly in the serializer to change it's type to a CharField or a IntegerField with choices, and then build the choices dynamically with a QuerySet.

Comment: I think my second question is exactly what you said with changing the type to `CharField` (or choices). Can you show me how?

Comment: @Ryan how does the adminview change my form actions of the restframework template?